# How does OAuth know where to send the callback request to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth, callback

I am curious about how OAuth knows to send the callback request to my dev machine. For example, when I implement facebook sign-in, and I sign in on my localhost, a request goes out to facebook to authenticate, and when successful, a callback gets sent to my localhost.

I understand I set my domain in the app to be localhost; however, localhost isn't a real registered domain, so how does facebook know which ip address to route my callback to?

Answer (score 0):

When creating the OAuth request, your app also needs to send along a callback URL. Your OAuth gem is more than likely handling this for you. Facebook then redirects back to that callback URL when authentication is done. You can usually customize the callback URL in the OAuth plugins, as well, if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook don't care what the callback url is, it just tell the browser redirect to the url you provided. So the dns lookup is inside your local browser and operating system.